# The SSL certificate used to load resources will be distrusted

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, ssl-certificate

```
from selenium import webdriver

opt = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
opt.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt);
driver.get("https://steamcommunity.com/")
```

I'm trying to run headless chrome, with Selenium. But keep getting the following error:

```
[0331/134342.207:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.", source: https://steamcommunity.com/ (0)
```

I have tried adding the --ignore-certificate-errors flag, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure this is the resolution you are looking for, but you can simply use the `http` `URL` `http://steamcommunity.com/` without the `SSL` `s` suffix. This will (I hope) prevent presenting this notification.